# How can I bind th:field to value of a radio button in a loop

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, radio-button, thymeleaf

In my HTML I iterate through a list of players (`spieler`).

```
<th:block th:each="spieler : ${runde.spieler}" >
```

Each player should have an unchecked radiobutton within the same group. When one radio button is checked I want to bind the value to an attribute of the particular player. The attribute is a boolean field (`zerrissen)`.

```
<input type="radio" th:value="${spieler.zerrissen}" th:field="*{runden[__${rundeStat.index}__].spieler[__${spielerStat.index}__].zerrissen}" />
```

For checkboxes the binding works fine. But with radio buttons its not working.

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{runden[__${rundeStat.index}__].spieler[__${spielerStat.index}__].gegangen}"/>
```

**How can I bind a radio button to a boolean attribute of my model within a loop?**

Edit:

In simple words, I have three `spieler`. Each `spieler` has a boolean attribute: `spieler.zerrissen`. And each `spieler` has a radio button on the view. If I hit the radio button of `spieler 1` and submit the form, the `@ModelAttribute spieler` - `spieler.zerrissen` of spieler 1` should be true. How can I achieve this?

the binding to my model is working because I use the `th:field` attribute. But using `th:field` means also that the generated name of each radio button is different and so I can check each radio button and not only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio button aren't designed to be used this way in thymeleaf.  A group of radio buttons should all have the same th:field (and selecting a radio button sets that field to the selected value).  You can't have a group of radio buttons that map to different fields.

I think you have two options here:

1. Use radio buttons mapped to a new field on your th:object.  You would add a getter and setter where the getter would loop through the spielers and return the index of the first spieler where where zerrissen == true and the setter would take the index of the spieler and set zerrissen = true on that object (and false on all others).  The value of the radio buttons would be the index of each spieler.
2. Some kind of javascript solution (use checkboxes and javascript/server side validation to make sure they only select one).

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you use both `th:value` and `th:field` tags.
According to documentation 
`<input th:field="${someThing}" />` will generate
`<input id="someThing" name="someThing" />`

but you need the same `name` for all of the radiobuttons, that is why it don't works.

So, try this :

**UPD try to set value as 0 or 1 not as true or false :**

```
<th:block th:each="spieler, iterStat : ${runde.spieler}" >
    <input type="radio" th:id="'spieler'+${iterStat.count}" 
           th:value="${spieler.zerrissen ? '1' : '0'}" name="spieler.zerrissen" th:checked=${spieler.zerissen} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the binding to the model does not work. Any solution for that?

Comment: sorry, seems the binding does not work. I need to bin this field: `*{runden[__${rundeStat.index}__].spieler[__${spielerStat.index}__].zerrissen` where should I set this in the input? For checkboxes this works. (Updated question)

Answer (score 0):

I just finnished a working solution. It was a little bit tricky for a beginner.

```
@Controller
@GetMapping("/radio") 
public String radioButton(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("cts", contMet());                   
    return "radio"; 
}
```

helper method contMet() was a solution for me:

```
public List<String> contMet() {

        List <String>cm = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator <Foo> iter =  cTR.findAll().iterator(); //cTR is a repository for the Foo class.
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            cm.add(iter.next().getType());
        }
        return cm;
    }
```

template:

```
<div th:each="mo: ${cts}" th:object="${foo}">
   <input type="radio" th:field="*{type}"  th:value="${mo}" th:text="${mo}" />
</div>
```

Foo object:

```
Public class Foo{
        @Id
        private String conId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        private String type; 
    ---etc
    --getters and setters
```